# Cosa vuol dire "dei beni"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-origin

Vorrei capire cosa significa l'espressione "dei beni", quando dovrei usarla, e da dove viene.

L'ho vista in questo contesto:

> Patrimonio culturale insieme dei beni culturali, artistici, ambientali, ecc. di una persona o un Paese.

Penso che qui significhi "together with all", ma non sono sicuro.

Quali sono altri esempi di buoni usi dell'espressione "dei beni"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si tratta del sostantivo *bene* (da non confondere con l'identico avverbio!). Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene2/)

> **bène²** s. m. [dall’avv. [*bene¹*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene1/)]. [...] **6.** concr. **a.** Ogni mezzo atto alla soddisfazione dei bisogni dell’uomo (nel linguaggio econ., quasi sempre sinon. di merce). In partic.: *b. economico*, qualsiasi mezzo, come sopra definito, di cui vi sia disponibilità relativamente limitata e sia quindi suscettibile di avere un prezzo, [...] In senso più ampio, *b. artistici*, *b. archeologici*, *b. ambientali*, ecc., il patrimonio nazionale sia naturale sia storico, inteso come insieme di ricchezze inalienabili che debbono essere valorizzate e tramandate come bene pubblico, perché soddisfano essenzialmente bisogni collettivi, tutelate quindi secondo le leggi dello stato e non secondo l’arbitrio di privati.

In questo caso *bene* quindi è simile all'inglese *good* (e.g. in *beni di consumo*=*consumer goods*) o *asset*, ma con un significato più ampio che riguarda anche oggetti intangibili o senza prezzo. Per cui la frase

> Patrimonio culturale: insieme dei beni culturali, artistici, ambientali, ecc. di una persona o un Paese..

può essere tradotta con

> Cultural patrimony: set of the cultural, artistic, environmental assets of a person or a country